# Passing and accessing URL variables in Google Sheet App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, crud

I am passing a URL variable to a Google App Script that opens a modal dialog. How do I get the html page script to access that variable value?

```js
// show html page for user selected row
// var i =  the user selected row from the previous HTML page
function myFunction2(i) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index2').setWidth(800).setHeight(600);

  //I know the value is being correctly delivered here because
  //it is being dumped out at the bottom of the page with this code
  row = ['RowPicked', i];//This is not html
  html.append(row);//This appends more html to the outout so it needs to be properly formatted html not google apps script code.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Update Selected Row');
}
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and about specific programming question. Asking for external resources is a reason to close question on this site. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've updated the question.

Comment: You need to read ["Client to Server Communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) carefully.  You can send a request to a google script with google.script.run when the page loads for example on document ready and have a function return that variable to the `.withSuccessHandler` and load it into the DOM with `document.getElementById().innerHTML=`